# Reverse array up to index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

How do I reverse a JavaScript array up to a given index? For example:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
var rev = array.reverse(5); // [4,3,2,1,0,6,5];
```

Comment: What did you try? Any loops written?

Comment: Did the zero magically dissapear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use slice

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];

var rev = arr.slice(5).concat(arr.slice(0,5)).reverse();

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(rev, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

That would give you `[4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6, 5]`, and you could make a function out of that

```js
function reverse(arr, n) {
    return arr.slice(n).concat(arr.slice(0,n)).reverse();
}

var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
var rev = reverse(arr, 5);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(rev, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: yep, or `arr.slice(n).concat(arr.slice(0,n)).reverse();`

Comment: @BennettAdams - that's a good idea, creating the array first, then calling `reverse` only once, I've edited to include that.